# Is the Hubble Telescope due to be retired and replaced this year?

Tags: hubble-telescope

Just curious i heard mention of the Hubble being retired soon...not sure if it was 2017...but the same article said there was a more updated telescope ready to replace it?

Comment: Current date is October 2018.    Here's a nice article on the replacement.    https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2016/04/28/nasas-new-gold-covered-telescope-will-put-the-hubble-to-shame/?utm_term=.5a01e60de0da

Comment: Excellent thanks for the link.... appreciated

Comment: nasa.gov might :-) have some info on current and future space-based telescope projects.

Answer (score 3):

The Hubble Space Telescope is not expected to be retired unless a failure of one or more components dramatically effects its capabilities and reduces the science return.  There is no provision currently for repairing Hubble, which depended on NASA's Space Shuttle program, no longer operating.  Lots more information about *HST* is at http://hubblesite.org/ and elsewhere.

NASA's next flagship space science mission is the James Webb Space Telescope, expected to be launched in late 2018.  This is a follow-on to Hubble's science mission and will be able to answer questions that Hubble is not designed to do. Among many other things it is expected to study some of the first stars and galaxies that formed not long after the beginning of the Universe, known as the Big Bang. 
Get much more information about *JWST* at http://webbtelescope.org/.